# Best Practice for storing MacOS iPhotos

Tags: macos, iphone, ssd, photos.app

Context:

1. macOS Catalina / Big Sur is used to store iPhone photos
2. Photos are not to be stored in the cloud / iCloud
3. Mac has a small SSD compared to the amount of iPhone photos that are to be stored

It is not an option to replace the MacOS SSD.

Given the above constraints: Is `best practice` to format a USB memory device and [somehow mount and point iPhotos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517) to the USB storage instead of the SSD? or is there a better process?

Comment: **Apple** has its own support article on the subject: [Move your Photos library to save space on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517) -- **NOTE**: "Always make sure that your storage device is turned on and available before opening Photos. If Photos can't find the device, it stops using the Photos library stored there."

Comment: @user3439894  Thanks for the suggestion in the link and will in all likeliness install a USB thumb drive to store the photos.  I wanted to be sure that there was not a better solution before doing so.

Comment: @gatorback Please make sure that you also maintain a backup of the Photos library. USB thumb drives are not known for reliability and can fail suddenly, permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Many people put their entire home folder on a drive that’s not the SSD / primary internal drive since the IO speed needed to access these files is rarely as sensitive as the OS itself. I don’t know about best practice, but first moving the photo library to another drive is an excellent start if you intend to have more library storage than the boot drive can accommodate. This has been stable for me for a decade. I do also use a tool to manage duplicated / merge libraries since sometimes I choose to import into a second library.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517
- https://fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/